# dotnet dev-certs https --> "There was a problem trusting HTTPS developer certificate"

Tags: .net, ssl, https, certificate

I am asking this because I am really out of ideas, tried everything that is in the internet, nothing helps...

for some reason the **dotnet dev-certs certificate** that my vsc generates is not trusted or accepted... (on any browser)... I will add some photos so you can see...

[Terminal log picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIT1V.png)

This is the Terminal log:

*$ dotnet dev-certs https --trust*
Trusting the HTTPS development certificate was requested. A confirmation prompt will be displayed if the certificate was not previously trusted. Click yes on the prompt to trust the certificate.
There was an error trusting HTTPS developer certificate.

the ssl certificate I installed for my angular client works fine on port https://localhost:4200
as you can see in this picture
[angular ssl that works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBxgi.png)

but for the dotnet port which is https://localhost:5001, the certificate is not trusted (see photos):

[certificate not trusted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQagE.png)

[error the browser gives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9sgA.png)

that makes it impossible for me to get information from the dotnet server to the Angular app...

would love some help... Thanks !

Comment: Happens to me too, can't find a solution either.